# NHibernate -- duplicate results when using collection cache

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-caches

I am getting very strange behavior from NHibernate when using the second level cache with multiple layers of bi-directonal parent-child(-grandchild) one-to-many relationships:

```
int id;

using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    var parent = new Parent();
    var child1 = parent.AddChild();
    child1.AddGrandChild();
    var child2 = parent.AddChild();
    child2.AddGrandChild();
    session.Save(parent);
    session.Flush(); // force id generation
    id = parent.Id;
}

using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    var parent = session.Get<Parent>(id);
    parent.Children.Should().HaveCount(2); // but is actually 3; second child duplicated
}
```

The second child, which has two grandchildren, gets duplicated in the collection, but with the same object id (`ReferenceEquals()` is `true`). When I disable caching for the `Parent.Children` collection, or set the fetching strategy to `Join`, the problem goes away. Any ideas how to find out what is happening here?

Entities:

```
class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual List<Child> children = new List<Child>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<Child> Children
    {
        get { return children.ToList(); }
    }

    public virtual Child AddChild()
    {
        var child = new Child(this);
        this.children.Add(child);
        return child;
    }
}

class Child
{
    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual List<GrandChild> grandChildren = new List<GrandChild>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<GrandChild> GrandChildren
    {
        get { return grandChildren.ToList(); }
    }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; protected set; }

    public virtual GrandChild AddGrandChild()
    {
        var grandChild = new GrandChild(this);
        this.grandChildren.Add(grandChild);
        return grandChild;
    }

}

class GrandChild
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Child Parent { get; protected set; }

    public GrandChild(Child parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

}
```

Mappings:

```
public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        Id(p => p.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        HasMany(p => p.Children)
            .Access.CamelCaseField()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Cache.ReadWrite();
        Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}

public class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        HasMany(c => c.GrandChildren)
            .Access.CamelCaseField()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Cache.ReadWrite();
        References(c => c.Parent);
        Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}

public class GrandChildMap : ClassMap<GrandChild>
{
    public GrandChildMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        References(c => c.Parent);
        Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

I worked around this issue by not enabling the cache for the child collections. Since I did it in the first place in order to avoid N+1 select issues with `fetch join` queries on children of cached entities, I did the following instead:

```
    public ChildMap()
    {
       // ...
        HasMany(c => c.GrandChildren) // removed Cache.ReadWrite() here
            /* ... */;

        // added IncludeAll() to make sure lazily fetched collections get cached
        Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll(); 
    }
```

I still don't understand what's going on here though, so any insight into this matter would still be welcome :-).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using transactions instead of seassion flushing? Like

```
using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
using(var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var parent = new Parent();
    [...]
    parent.Save();
    transaction.Commit();
    id = parent.Id;
}
```

Maybe that helps. I once had a similar problem that I could solve with using transactions.

Comment: No, that's not it ... 
1) I don't do the flush "instead of a commit" (which wouldn't make any sense anyway) but to force the generation if an id
2) Since I open separate sessions for the write and the subsequent read, both operations have their own implicit transaction anyway
3) Usually I use explicit transactions, I just left them out here for brevity

Comment: To clarify: In the "real" code, the two sessions / transactions correspond to separate web service requests.

Comment: I know this is a very old question but in case someone wonders, For NHibernate Second Level Cache to work correctly, you must use explicit transactions.